# Using javascript to validate form and return text to html

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am using `asp.net` to build a form and trying to validate it using `javascript`

The validation seems to be working correctly, however it is not inserting the text into the `<p></p>` tags. Am I not using the `document.getElementById("errorEmail").innerHTML = text;` correctly or what?

Below is my code, I added an `alert` to help trouble shoot and the `alert` is working, so I do know that the conditional is working and is setting a value to `text`

```
    <script>
    function validateForm() {
    alert("testing");

    var x, text;

    x = document.forms["form1"]["textEmail"].value;

    if (x == null || x == "" || x == "Email") {
        alert("testing if conditional");
        text = "Please input your eamail";
        alert(text);
    }
    document.getElementById("errorEmail").innerHTML = text;

    }
    </script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">

        <p id="errorEmail"> </p>
        <asp:TextBox ID="textEmail" runat="server" placeholder="Email" name="email"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Button ID="buttonSubmit"  runat="server" Text="Submit Request" OnClientClick="return validateForm();"/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no problem with that way you are setting up the text.

I don't know how asp.net work but form JavaScript point of view I can say that you should return false in case of error. Seems like your page is getting refreshed right after the submission.

```
function validateForm() {
    var x, text;
    x = document.forms["form1"]["textEmail"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "" || x == "Email") {
        text = "Please input your eamail";
        document.getElementById("errorEmail").innerHTML = text;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is the fiddle I have setup, Hope it helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/91wbrzL8/

Comment: You don't know how `asp` works, well it does not matter because you know how `javasrcipt` works and you solved this issue for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is the problematic line (that is not valid to get the reference to the form and later to the text field):

```
x = document.forms["form1"]["textEmail"].value;
```

Instead use:

```
x = document.getElementById("textEmail").value;
```

Comment: Those two examples work the same for me, both will show the alert. however it still is not setting the value of `text` in the `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your code to show the text is correct, the problem is that you have a javascript error somewhere else.  Debug your javascript to find where the error is coming from.